# Setting DNS for Docker daemon on OS with systemd

Tags: dns, docker, systemd

The default DNS for Docker (e.g. 8.8.8.8) is blocked where I work, so I want to change the default. I've been able to do this using

```
$ docker daemon --dns <mydnsaddress>
```

but I want to do this using a systemd drop-in instead, since the official Docker docs recommend this way. I've made a `/etc/systemd/system/docker.service.d/dns.conf` file, and used things like this:

```
[Service]
DNS=<mydnsaddress>
```

But I just have no idea what the variable name is supposed to be. How do I set this? More importantly, is there a page that documents all config variables that can be used in systemd drop-ins for Docker?

(btw, this is Docker 1.9 on Ubuntu 15.10, although I don't suspect any bugs)

Comment: The docker documentation describes how the DOCKER_OPTS can be set in the /etc/default/docker file: https://docs.docker.com/engine/articles/configuring/

Answer (score 42, accepted):

All `.conf` files in `/etc/systemd/system/docker.service.d` overrule the settings from the `/usr/lib/systemd/system/docker.service` file, which is almost what you tried.

Instead of putting a `DNS=..`  line in, you need to copy the `ExecStart=` part from the `/usr/lib/systemd/system/docker.service` file to `dns.conf` (or `mydocker.conf`). Add `--dns $ip` after the `daemon` part of the `ExecStart`. E.g.:

```
[Service]
ExecStart=
ExecStart=/usr/bin/docker daemon --dns 192.168.1.1 -H fd://
```

Where the `192.168.1.1` is the ip of the dns server.

Now restart docker via systemctl and docker should now restart with your own dns. (Checkable via `systemctl status docker.service | grep dns`).

Note that the empty `ExecStart=` is required, as systemctl only will overrule the ExecStart if it is cleared first.

Also note that a `systemctl daemon-reload` is needed after editing files in `/etc/systemd/system/`.

Last remark is that on some systems `docker.service` is not located in `/usr/lib/systemd/system/`, but in `/lib/systemd/system/`.

Comment: Thank you this works.  But is is quite convoluted … this is something that used to be easier, before systemd.

Comment: For docker 18.06.0-ce on Ubuntu Bionic I needed `/usr/bin/dockerd --dns a.b.c.d -H fd://` (where a.b.c.d is your DNS server IP address)

Comment: It is also possible to put the option in `/etc/docker/daemon.json`. It is unfortunately somewhat poorly documented; its format is not described in the man page, but there is something in the [online documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/#daemon-configuration-file).

Answer (score 3):

Yes I agreed to previous answer given by @steviethecat but this changes overwrite to default when docker restart so I followed below steps. Using Docker version 18.09.2,

I followed link https://success.docker.com/article/using-systemd-to-control-the-docker-daemon

```
sudo systemctl edit docker //this opens new file use as overwrite file.
```

add below lines. Make sure you have  ExecStart= before setting this value. Above given link having details.

```
[Service]
ExecStart=
ExecStart=/usr/bin/dockerd --dns 192.168.1.1 -H fd://
```

once above lines added to file, execute below lines.

```
sudo systemctl daemon-reload
systemctl restart docker
systemctl status docker
```

Comment: You can configure `/etc/docker/daemon.json` alternatively, then no override of systemd unit is necessary.