# How to change dockerd parameters with systemd?

Tags: docker, systemd

Since 16.04 release Ubuntu stopped using Upstart and switch to Systemd for its init system.

How can I change default DOCKER_OPTS parameters?

Comment: This question is closely linked to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33784295/setting-dns-for-docker-daemon-on-os-with-systemd?rq=1 .

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**Execute following commands as root (or with sudo).**

To extend the default docker unit file with additional configuration options, first create a configuration directory in `/etc/systemd/system/`:

```
mkdir /etc/systemd/system/docker.service.d/
```

Now put a configuration file in `/etc/systemd/system/docker.service.d/`. It's imperative that the file name must end with the `.conf` suffix:

```
touch /etc/systemd/system/docker.service.d/docker.conf
```

To change daemon parameters create configuration file with following content (ex. adds `--dns` option):

```
[Service]
ExecStart=
ExecStart=/usr/bin/dockerd -H fd:// --dns 8.8.8.8
```

After saving docker unit file, before systemd will take it into account, systemd needs to reload modified data:

```
systemctl daemon-reload
```

Finally docker service can be restarted:

```
systemctl restart docker
```

You can check that status by running:

```
systemctl status docker.service | grep dns
```

## Default

On Ubuntu default configuration is located in `/lib/systemd/system/docker.service`.

## Resources

- [Control and configure Docker with systemd](https://docs.docker.com/engine/admin/systemd/)
- [Modifying Existing Unit Files](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/7/html/System_Administrators_Guide/sect-Managing_Services_with_systemd-Unit_Files.html#sect-Managing_Services_with_systemd-Unit_File_Modify)

Comment: To simplify things you can use `systemctl edit docker.service` and this will open docker.service file in a text editor no matter the location.